# Show Logout Modal after 1800 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have installed a PHP script which logs the user out when 1800 seconds without activity have passed. So when you click a link when 1800 seconds have passed, you will be logged out.

I want this to be real time. So if 1800 seconds have passed, show the user a bootstrap modal. This needs jQuery and that is not a problem at all.

Example;

```
if (timeHasPassed > 1800 sec) {
    show();
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setTimeout function of javascript. This will gives alert after 1 second. you can change the time whatever you want.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  alert("show logout model"); // call your function show(); here
}, 1000);
```

**Reference** : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: But what if I want it to be 1800 seconds? This is milliseconds right?